# ffmpeg timelapse very slow

Tags: performance, ffmpeg, timelapse

I'm using

```
ffmpeg -i IMG_5299.MOV -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -r 60 -filter:v "setpts=0.0015*PTS" -an IMG_5299-speedup.mkv
```

to create a 600x timelapse out of a H.265 4K 60fps video. I just want `ffmpeg` to pick every 600th frame and put it together to a new 60fps video. No interpolation, no nothing. Still, I only get 0.2 fps on a very recent i5-7600T CPU, while converting the same video without speedup using

```
ffmpeg -i IMG_5299.MOV -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -an IMG_5299-2.mkv
```

gives me 5 fps. So why is speeding the video up 25x times slower than just converting it? Is it doing any nifty interpolation for each frame out of 600 frames or something?

EDIT: That's the statusline I get after several minutes of encoding:

```
frame=  447 fps=0.2 q=28.0 size=   68639kB time=00:00:06.56 bitrate=85611.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=147650 speed=0.00233x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's slow because you're picking one out of every 666 frames. All of those 666 frames have to be decoded and filtered before one frame can be encoded. Let's say your system can decode at 333 frames per second, then your encoding speed ceiling is 0.5 fps.

You can profile your decoding throughput using

```
ffmpeg -i IMG_5299.MOV -an -f null -
```

You can speed up encoding by only demuxing keyframe packets from the MOV.

```
ffmpeg -discard nokey -i IMG_5299.MOV -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -r 60 -vf "setpts=0.0015*PTS" -an IMG_5299-speedup.mkv
```